# Setting soap request security header in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap

I am not so familiar with soap service but trying to consume one from a spring boot application. This runs but throws exception as I was not able to set the header as per below soap request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:web="http://webservices.service.company.com/">
    <soapenv:Header
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Pa$$wrd</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        ...
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
public class SoapClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.company.ws.wsdl");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public SoapClient soapClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("localhost:8080/service/myservice");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
}
```

SoapClient class

```
@Component
public class SoapClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public CustSearchResponse getCustomer(CustomerSearchRequest custRequest) {
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<CustomerSearchRequest> request =
                objectFactory.createCustomerSearchRequest(custRequest);
        JAXBElement response = (JAXBElement)getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
                request);
        return (CustSearchResponse) response.getValue();
    }
}
```

Looked few examples but it seems so complex and I am not sure how that works with my soap header. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

**Update**
Tried to add securityInterceptor as below

```
@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor security = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    security.setSecurementActions(WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP + " " + WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    security.setSecurementPasswordType(WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
    security.setSecurementUsername("username");
    security.setSecurementPassword("password");
    return security;
}
```

and updated the SoapClient bean as below:

```
@Bean
public SoapClient soapClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
    client.setDefaultUri("localhost:8080/service/myservice");
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[]{ securityInterceptor() });
    return client;
}
```

Now I am getting below error:

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Must Understand check failed for header SOAP-ENV : {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38)

    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:795)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:605)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:542)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:394)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:388)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:378)
```

Comment: are you able to get response using postman?

Comment: You haven't configured anything for security, which is why it fails. You will need to setup the security interceptor for your `SoapClient` to adhere to the WSDL, you need to pass a username and password. I also doubt that yuour service is running on your localhost so the URL is probably incorrect as well?

Comment: thanks for the comment. Yes the url is wrong, I just used this for privacy. I am little confused about security configuration. DO u have any link that I can use ? Most of them seemed complicated and I was not sure how to implement that.